# Bash script to download Signal APK file from official Signal website

Tags: bash, curl, https, wget

I am trying to write a BASH script to:

1. Download the latest Signal APK file from https://signal.org/android/apk/ once a month (via a cron script)
   1.1) Normally the download is initiated by clicking on the "Download" button on the website
2. From Chrome, when you right-click on the "Download" button and select "Inspect":

```
<input type="button" class="button is-large" value="Download" onclick="location.href = 'https://updates.signal.org/android/Signal-Android-website-prod-universal-release-6.25.5.apk';">
```

I've tried using wget and curl to download the file without any luck.
E.g.

```
wget --no-parent -r -p -U Mozilla --no-check-certificate -A '*.apk' https://signal.org/android/apk/
```

Comment: You forgot to post in your question the output (stdout and stderr) and the exit code from `wget`.

Comment: May be a better script language like Python would make more sense. With python you could download the html page, extract the download link and fingerprint, then check locally if you already have the file and if not download the provided APK file.

Answer (score 0):

This element

```
<input type="button" class="button is-large" value="Download" onclick="location.href = 'https://updates.signal.org/android/Signal-Android-website-prod-universal-release-6.25.5.apk';">
```

make use of JavaScript, `wget` does not support execution of JavaScript, so you either need to write some script which will find value being assigned to location.href or use tool supporting JavaScript execution e.g. headless browser.